# como retornar el precio de un producto, que se encuentra en un array

Tags: javascript, array, funciones

*Escriba una función getProductPrice(productName) que tome el parámetro productName, el nombre del producto. La función busca un objeto producto con ese nombre (propiedad name) en el array products y devuelve su precio (propiedad price). Si no se encuentra ningún producto con este nombre, la función debe devolver null.*

```
Declare la función getProductPrice(productName).
Al llamar a getProductPrice("Radar") devuelve 1300.
Al llamar a getProductPrice("Grip") devuelve 1200.
Al llamar a getProductPrice("Scanner") devuelve 2700.
Al llamar a getProductPrice("Droid") devuelve 400.
Al llamar a getProductPrice("Engine") devuelve null.
```

con un ciclo for, recorri el array, luego mediante un if el nombre del producto que tengo el array con el nombre de producto que recibe mi function getProductPrice, si la comparacion me da true, entonces retorne el precio del producto con return product.price y de lo contrario que me return null

```
const products = [
  { name: "Radar", price: 1300, quantity: 4 },
  { name: "Scanner", price: 2700, quantity: 3 },
  { name: "Droid", price: 400, quantity: 7 },
  { name: "Grip", price: 1200, quantity: 9 },
];



function getProductPrice(productName) {
  for (const product of products) {
    if (product.name === productName) {
     
      return product.price;
     
    }
    return null;
    
  }
}
getProductPrice("Radar")
getProductPrice("Scanner")
getProductPrice("Engine")
```

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado? ¿Qué errores tienes? Donde está el [Ejemplo Mínimo Verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) de lo que has hecho y fundamentalmente parte del código que has utilizado (en texto, no imagen) que se menciona en el [tour] y en [ask].

Answer (score 0):

ya pude dar solucion

```
function getProductPrice(productName) {
  const products = [
  { name: "Radar", price: 1300, quantity: 4 },
  { name: "Scanner", price: 2700, quantity: 3 },
  { name: "Droid", price: 400, quantity: 7 },
  { name: "Grip", price: 1200, quantity: 9 },
];
  for (const product of products) {
    if (product.name === productName) {
     
      return product.price;
     
    }

    
  }
      return null;
}
getProductPrice("Radar")
getProductPrice("Scanner")
getProductPrice("Engine")
```